# Unable to import Django model from the other app during migration roll-back

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I'm creating a data-migration for the `new_app` with the possibility to roll it back.

```
# This is `new_app` migration
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(import_data, reverse_code=delete_data)
    ]
```

This migration adds some data to the model defined in other app: `my_other_app`. To import the model where I want to update or delete records I use `apps.get_model()` method.

```
# This is `new_app` migration
def import_data(apps, schema_editor):   
    model = apps.get_model('my_other_app', 'MyModel')
```

It works like charm when I apply migrations. But when I run try to roll back the migration with the `:~> manage.py migrate new_app zero` I get exception: `LookupError: No installed app with label 'my_other_app'.` Model import in roll back code:

```
# This is `new_app` migration
def delete_data(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_model = apps.get_model('my_other_app', 'MyModel')
```

The code for model import is identical, but why it doesn't work during migration roll back? For now I have a workaround with straight model `import` during roll-back. Don't know if it may cause troubles in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that `dependencies` includes the latest migration from the other app that you're referencing. eg:

```
dependencies = [
    'my_other_app.0001_initial',
]
```

Also, make sure `'my_other_app'` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.